# script moved to subdirectory post creating a venv, unable to find pip package originally installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I created myscript.py file which was added to the same directory as was my **main**.py file. Then I created venv and then installed all packages using pip3, including a package named xyz. I can see these packages installed at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xyz. Note that myscript.py file is refering to a function in xyz package.

When myscript.py was in the same directory as **main**.py everything worked just fine. Then I created a subdirectory called 'proto' and moved myscript.py under that subdirectory and also I created an empty **init**.py file inside that subdirectory. When I try to execute **main**.py it gives following error.
ImportError: No Module named 'xyz'
Is it because subdirectory was created after the venv?
How can I fix this?

Here is my new file structure

```
c:\project\code
            |__main__.py
            |some other files
            \proto
                  |__init__.py
                  |myscript.py
```

Comment: it seems that you installed te packages while outside of the virtual environment. run activate, then pip freeze, and see if the relevant package is indeed installed.

Comment: why is there a underscore main.py ? you are sure there is no import of xyz in another file and you use it elsewhere ?

Comment: @Roy2012, yes the package was installed before venv was created. So it is not listed when I ran pip freeze, but how do I fix it now? do I need to reinstall the package or is there a way to fix it in the venv?

Comment: @user3732793 __main.py__ was created while new project instance was created, I didn't bother to change it.

Comment: that is a bit odd. when you have installed the package globally it should be available where ever your pyth script runs. However you could source your venv and just run pip install xyz again

Comment: since you're working in a virtual environment (or so it seems), you should install the package within the virtual env. Do do that: (1) activate the env; (2) run pip install <package>.

Comment: Thanks guys, the suggestions gave me a rough idea what was going on. I also figured out that the package it was complaining about was package was not installed by me, it was installed by a third party sdk. So it didn't figure in the pip list, instead it was in dist_package, so that was a part of the mystery. Then I located pyvenn.cgf file in my env folder and set include-system-site-packages = true (default it was set to false). Now my new folder structure works fine!! Thanks Roy2012 user3732793

Answer (score 0):

locate the file pyvenv.cfg file in your env folder.
edit the following setting:

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```